# How to tell Geometry Node to place one object next to another dynamically?

Tags: procedural, geometry-nodes

I come from a game development background and am not quite sure if this is the right way of thinking in Blender, but let's assume that i have the following tasks:

- Create a tool that will generate procedural building, based on pre-made main parts:

1. Floor
2. Middle ground
3. roof

and each of these parts can also be created through a different Geometry Node, what i can't find is the follow:

If i create a **Floor** that is 3 meters high, what node should i use so that the *Middle ground** start at 3 meters (right above the floor), and then after x-Middle grounds, the **Roof** should also be placed on top accordingly.

This is the easiest example that i can think of to solve my problem, but i will eventually need more complex setups that will detect "corners", for example if it's a grid based node, is there a way to detect "corners" and whole edges ? so that (x=0;y=n) gives you the cells of the first column of the grid.

Can anyone please point me at the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it with this node setup:

(and although you might not wanna hear it: there is so "magic" checkbox or settings ...it is just easy math....)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Haha i wasn't expecting a checkbox either, but was basically looking for an "object reference" to use its data, Question: what's exactly the "Line" node doing in your setup ?

Comment: The line object helps me to "define" the height of the building. Since the line has as much vertices as you define in "count" i will instance then the cubes on that vertices.

Comment: I see, i downloaded the Blend file and the manually entered "2.1" value still feel like an issue to me, is there a way to automate that ? the problem is this, if you enter edit mod to the "middle" part and reduce its height, you get this issue: https://i.imgur.com/D7a2b9O.png  unless you play around with the 2.1 value, is there a way to automate that ? especially considering that the middle parts can be made out of a Collection which contains objects with different heights, i assumed ObjectInfo would help, but it gives the scale (1,1,1) when what i need is "Dimensions", any tips ?

Comment: Found it! i replaced that "2.1" value node with the Bounding Box Max value (https://i.imgur.com/FDtnQ6E.png), it does what i want now (https://i.imgur.com/zQDs9ml.mp4) , the roof still acting a bit strange but i'll find a way to fix it, thanks a lot @Chris !

Comment: Great! Would be nice if you could tap on the checkmark left to my answer if it helped you! Thank you!

Comment: Oh i did since the first comment but it said i have to wait for x-hours or something, it's accepted as the correct answer now, thanks again mate, i really appreciate it :)

Comment: You are welcome